# How do I add another cart.item from the liquid code in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I would like to add another option to a product in the shopping cart.  When existing options are rendered on the cart page, they are printed with:

```
{%- for line_item in cart.items -%}
```

This renders list items, example below:

```
<li class="line-item__property">Age: 42</li>
```

In the example

above, the customer entered their age as 42 on the product page and it was then displayed from cart.liquid.

I would like to add another option to the cart from cart.liquid.  I can't simply add another

since that's just what's rendered and passed to the front-end, so after clicking Checkout it won't be there anymore.

Is it possible to update the cart from the liquid code here, potentially using javascript?  Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can add items to the cart many ways. The traditional old school way is to do a POST to the cart endpoint, with the ID and quantity of the item you want to add. That has worked for nearly 18 years. The new school ways would be to update the cart with a Storefront API call perhaps, or with a cart transform API App call. It is way beyond a SO post to provide you with any code answer as you have not provided nearly enough details in exactly what you're trying to do, and why, but rest assured, you can do it! Use JS is my advice.